# what are the pramanas that Abhinavagupta uses to prove Appearances come from Consciousness?

Tags: kashmiri-shaivism

I heard that he quoted dharmakirti's pramanavinisccaya to prove that objects have no self existance but are existing in Consciousness.what other proofs and pramanas has he used in his works from Tantraloka to his other works to prove his main thesis that Consciousness is the source of reality?